# Converting recursion to dynamic & calculating its time complexity

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I'm solving a code and my recursion function came to something like this->

```
int rec(n)
{

  if(n>=(n/2+n/3+n/4))
  {
      return n;
  }


  else
  {

     return  rec(n/2) + rec(n/3) + rec(n/4); 

  }

}
```

I was wondering what would be the time complexity of this function?

I think the recurrence relation would be-

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + T(n/4) + f(n)
```

How to solve this recurrence relation? What would the value of f(n) be in this case?

Also how would one go about converting this into dynamic programming?

The code I have written to convert this into dynamic is-

```
    long long  rec(long long n)
{
    long long c[n]; // The number range is between 1 to 10^9


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    c[n]=0;


    if(n>=(n/2+n/3+n/4))
    {
        c[n]=n;
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        if (c[n]==0)
        c[n]=c[n/2]+c[n/3]+c[n/4];
        return c[n];
    }

}
```

However, after converting the recursion to dynamic my program refuses to show the correct answer. I think I I haven't converted it into dynamic programming properly. Could you please guide me on how to go about doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb: [Masters theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). It's `O(n ^ (a / b))`, i. e. polinomial.

Comment: Neither of these functions use indentation consistently, and due to the inconsistent indentation it is quite easy to misread them. I refuse to read such an eyesore. Take some pride, and fix your indentation. Hopefully others will follow my lead.

Comment: Your second piece of code doesn't compile and has obvious errors due to missing braces.  Please give us the actual code you ran so we can give meaningful feedback.

Comment: Alright necessary changes made to the question posted.

Answer (score 1):

The if (n >= (n/2 + n/3 + n/4)) basically is equivalent to if (n <= 0). n can't be less than 0, so it's ok to write if (n == 0) return n; This means the time complexity is given by the  following recurrence equation:

```
T(0) = 1
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + T(n/4)
```

Since the division of the problem in smaller problems is not symmetrical (and because n/2 + n/3 + n/4 = 13n/12, which is more than n) in first approximation (a big one) I would say between O(nlogn) and O(n^2). I tried to prove it's O(nlog2n) but didn't check out(by log2n I mean log in base 2 of n):

```
T(n) <= cnlog2n
```

from now on I will write just logn

```
T(n) <= cn/2*logn/2 + cn/3*logn/3 + cn/4*logn/4
      = cn/2*logn - cn/2*log2 + cn/3*logn - cn/3*log3 + cn/4*logn - cn/4*log4
      = cn/2*logn - cn/2 + cn/3*logn - cn/3*log3 + cn/4*logn - cn/2
      = 13/12*cn*logn - cn(log3/3 - 1)
```

which is not less than or equal to cnlogn

O(n^2) can be proven to be true like this:

```
if T(n) = O(n^2) then T(n) <= cn^2
T(n) <= c(n/2)^2 + c(n/3)^2 + c(n/4)^2
      = cn^2/4 + cn^2/9 + cn^2/16
      = 15cn^2/36 <= cn^2
```

so the O(n^2) hypothesis is true, however it might not be very accurate.
You can try another hypothesis between O(nlogn) and O(n^2) and see if they are true like I did above.